# Filtering records by passing query in function from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, react-native, object

I want to fetch records by passing query arguments to a function in JavaScript.

```
const data = [{
    name: "ab",
    class: 1,
    grade: "A",
    teacher: {
      teacherName: "tab",
      age: 34,
      school: "ab pblc scl"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "cd",
    class: 2,
    grade: "B",
    teacher: {
      teacherName: "efg",
      age: 35,
      school: "cd pblc scl"
    }
  }
]
```

My filter function arguments (1st argument is array and 2nd is query which can be anything)

These are some test conditions.

`filterMe(data,{name : "cd", class:"2",teacherName:"efg"})` should return whole object

```
{
   name: "cd",
   class: 2,
   grade: "B",
   teacher: {
      teacherName: "efg",
      age: 35,
      school: "cd pblc scl"
   }
}
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: please add the code snippets you have to achieve this

Comment: I have done with single objects not with nested. for single object solution please check the answer by @Kobe

Comment: A question about your params: `{name : "cd", class:"2",teacherName:"efg"}` is more complicated in my opinion than `{name : "cd", class:"2", teacher: {teacherName:"efg"}}` so would that be an option? The first version requires a recursive search to find the nested key, the second does not which makes it way easier.

Comment: yes @assoron it is but thats what I have suppose to do.. anyway you can also tell me the code for {name : "cd", class:"2", teacher: {teacherName:"efg"}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` to get each key from the provided object, and check if every pair is the same as the filter condition using `every`. If the value is an object, recursively call the function:

```js
const data = [{
    name: "ab",
    class: 1,
    grade: "A",
    teacher: {
      teacherName: "tab",
      age: 34,
      school: "ab pblc scl"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "cd",
    class: 2,
    grade: "B",
    teacher: {
      teacherName: "efg",
      age: 35,
      school: "cd pblc scl"
    }
  }
]

const advFilter = (d, f) => d.filter(o => nestedEvery(o, f))
const nestedEvery = (o, v) => Object.entries(v).every(([k,v]) => typeof v === 'object' ? nestedEvery(o[k], v) : o[k] === v)

const log = console.log
log(advFilter(data, { name: "cd", class: 2, teacher: { teacherName: 'efg' } })) // returns cd
log(advFilter(data, { name: "cd", class: 2, teacherName: 'efg' })) // returns []
log(advFilter(data, { name: "ab", class: 1, teacher: { teacherName: 'tab' } })) // returns ab
```

> Note, You cannot simply reference a nested property name without specifying the path to which it belongs, as there could be multiple properties with the same name.

Comment: I am looking for the code which will work with nested objects. else I have already achieved the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot but can we pass just {name : "cd", class:"2",teacherName:"efg"} and make it work through recursive search ?

Comment: @jeetdeveloper Read the note I put at the end. Sure it is possible, but it is time consuming, inefficient and unreliable. Why can't you just reference the path?

Comment: No problem. I feel that the problem lies on your side where you pass the filtering object, since you should be able to know what the object looks like if you're filtering by it. If you need anymore help, just ask, and if you think this answer has helped you, feel free to mark it the correct answer 

Answer (score -1):

I have tested for some of the test cases, I think my code is working.
Give it a try:

```js
const data = [{
    name: "ab",
    class: 1,
    grade: "A",
    teacher: {
      teacherName: "tab",
      age: 34,
      school: "ab pblc scl"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "cd",
    class: 2,
    grade: "B",
    teacher: {
      teacherName: "efg",
      age: 35,
      school: "cd pblc scl"
    }
  }
]

function filterMe(data, query){
  result = data.filter( x => {
    return Object.keys(x).some( y => {
        
        if(y === "teacher"){
          return Object.keys(x[y]).some( u => {
            return Object.keys(query).some( q => {
                return query[q] === x[y][u]
            })
          })
        }else{
           return Object.keys(query).some( q => {
                return query[q] === x[y]
            })
        }
      })
    })

  console.log(result);
}

filterMe(data,{name : "cd", class:"2",teacherName:"efg"})
```

Comment: Your code returns both of the objects. Also, what if OP was to use a different property than teacher?

Comment: I don't think it returns both the objects if we query for one. But this is not targeted to solve a generalized solution. It only solves the specific problem.

Comment: It returns both with `{name : "ab", class:"2",teacherName:"efg"}`

Comment: You could also write your function much cleaner like [this](https://pastebin.com/zLZWRt64)